# How can i support iOS Version 10.3 with swift 2.3 project

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

Good Day,

Lastweek i updated my Xcode from 8.2 to 8.3, In my project i used swift 2.3 version. I tried to use multiple version of xcode to my Mac but when i use the older version of Xcode i can't run the project on devices that has iOS Version 10.3.1

I don't know how to run swift 2.3 to iOS Version 10.3.1

Note: My Project still not uploaded on App Store.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's said in [release note](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html) clearly that Xcode 8.3 `no longer` supports `Swift 2.3` version. So you need to migrate your projects containing `Swift 2.3` code to `Swift 3` syntax by opening the project and choosing Edit > Convert > To Current Swift Syntax.

Comment: @nicoaureliovillanueva if you satisfy with my answer then you would accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You need DeveloperDiskImage for iOS version 10.3 to run your project on device(iOS 10.3) using xcode 8.2.

Download Xcode 8.3.2 from [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/) and copy **10.3 (14E269)** folder inside DeviceSupport from the downloaded Xcode using path **Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/** and paste it into  **Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/** path in your existing Xcode 8.2 in Finder.

Comment: this helped me a lot! The project is too large to convert it for a quick fix. If I can download the app and run it, why can't I build it on my device? Thanks again!